# Writing to S3 via Kinesis Stream or Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have events that keep coming which I need to put to S3. I am trying to evaluate if I muse use Kinesis Stream or Firehose. I also want to wait for few minutes before writing to S3 so that the object is fairly full.

Based on my reading of Kinesis Data stream, I have to create an analytics app which will then be used to invoke a lambda. I will then have to use the lambda to write to S3. Or Kinesis Data Streams can directly write to lambda somehow? I could not find anything indicating the same.

Firehose is not charged by hour(while stream is). So is firehose a better option for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or Kinesis Data Streams can directly write to lambda somehow?

Data Streams can't write directly to S3. Instead [Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html) can do this:

> delivering real-time streaming data to destinations such as Amazon **Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3)**, Amazon Redshift, Amazon Elasticsearch Service (Amazon ES), Splunk, and any custom HTTP endpoint or HTTP endpoints owned by supported third-party service providers, including Datadog, MongoDB, and New Relic.

What's more Firehose allows you to [buffer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-configure.html) the records before writing them to S3. The writing can happen based on buffer size or time. In addition to that you can [process the records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-transform.html) using lambda function before writing to S3.

Thus, colectively it seems that Firehose is more suited to your use-case then Data Streams.

Comment: Thanks. I am still trying to understand in what case firehose is inferior? It is just the data retention and that in streams we can execute direct sql queries. Am I right that since I do not need sql queries and neither do I need to hold the data for more than 24 hours, Firehose will be the way to go from this reasoning as well?

Comment: @curiousengineer FH is not real time. Due to buffering its pseudo-real time, which may not be acceptable in many use-cases. We can also read directly from FH. Based on your description, FH seems as better choice then DS.

Comment: Thanks. I am pumping data into S3 and then to snowflake. And in fact some delay is better. In fact I want a baketime that firehose offers. Thanks

Comment: @curiousengineer No problem. Glad i could help:-)